# Calculate data in SQL without using SELECT statement?

Tags: database, informix

I wanna ask whether it is possible to calculate data without using a SELECT statement?
For example:

```
Dept      salary
IT         4000
IT         3800
Marketing   3500
Marketing   3900
Operation   4000
```

The data already in an order, but is it possible to come out with this output?

```
Dept      salary
IT         4000
IT         3800
Total:2    Total:7800

Marketing   3500
Marketing   3900
Total:2    Total:7400

Operation   4000
Total:1     Total:4000
```

without using a SELECT statement?

My supervisor asked me to find another way to calculate without using select statement. And I am wondering whether it is possible or not? If possible, what is the other way to calculate?

Comment: The data is not already in order, as SQL databases don't usually have an internal order.  And no, you would need a query to extract information out.

Comment: Thank you. It is my first time. is it possible not using select statement?

Comment: Do you need this exact formatting?  If you just want that information, it would be easy to do a `GROUP BY` aggregation.

Comment: I already done the order. the dept the only one that been in order. in ascending order. so,it is not possible to calculate the total for both dept n salary without using select statement?

Comment: Yes, I think you will need a `SELECT` statement to get your output.

Comment: i have done everything and finished it. But they ask me to find another way to calculate without using select statement.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: As far as any RDBMS goes you will have to use "SELECT" statement. If the reason for NOT using SELECT is performance, then may be you would like to have a running sum table and select from there.

Comment: my supervisor asked me to find another way to retrieve the calculation without using select statement. do you any idea on whether it is possible or not?

Comment: I suppose you could use a stored procedure with the data stored somehow in a LIST type containing appropriate elements of a ROW type.  But that's convoluted beyond belief.  If the data is stored in a database, a SELECT statement is how you get the data back out.  Even then, it would be easier to wrap a SELECT statement up in the stored procedure.

Comment: i already done everything and i basically use SELECT statement to retrieve the result. and I am still wondering how to retrieve data without using SELECT statement. I really in a clueless state.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could create a view, call the view and print the values in a given column.  Not sure why your supervisor would advise against using a SELECT statement (DML), as that is used to *select* matching data from the db.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, there is no way to get the data from the table without a SELECT, the database server can calculate the total sum for you, so you don't have to retrieve all the values in the client and do the sum there, but no matter what, you still have to do a SELECT

Now who does the SELECT is a different matter, you could write a simple function or spl that will ran the SELECT for you and return the values you want.
Technically speaking (from the application point of view) you are not doing a 'SELECT  ....' statement, you are doing a 'EXECUTE PROCEDURE give_me_what_i_want()'  and the SELECT is done in the server.

for example:

```
D:\infx\ids12>dbaccess stores7 -
Database selected.
> create table test (emp char(20),dept char(20), salary int);
Table created.
> insert into test values ('emp1','IT',3800);
1 row(s) inserted.
> insert into test values ('emp2','IT',4000);
1 row(s) inserted.
> insert into test values ('emp3','Marketing',3900);
1 row(s) inserted.
> insert into test values ('emp4','Marketing',3500);
1 row(s) inserted.
> insert into test values ('emp5','Operation',4000);
1 row(s) inserted.
>
```

Assuming this is what you are after:

```
> select dept,sum(salary) from test group by dept;
dept                            (sum)
Operation                        4000
IT                               7800
Marketing                        7400
3 row(s) retrieved.
>
```

you could do something like:

```
> create procedure get_salaries(vdept char(20)) returning int;
> return (select sum(salary) from test where dept matches vdept);
> end procedure;

Routine created.

> execute procedure get_salaries('IT');
(expression)
        7800
1 row(s) retrieved.

> execute procedure get_salaries('Operation');
(expression)
        4000
1 row(s) retrieved.

> execute procedure get_salaries('Marketing');
(expression)
        7400
1 row(s) retrieved.

> execute procedure get_salaries('*');
(expression)
       19200
1 row(s) retrieved.
>
```

You can tell your supervisor you are not doing a SELECT, just running a SPL and the SPL calculates the sum value by magic ;)

Comment: Yes just like Adrian Russo told you :)